# How to show file context menu in a grid with files

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid

I've got a WPF grid in which each row represents a file on disk.

[image: grid]

What I'd like to do is; when someone right-clicks on a row to show the same context menu as Windows Explorer shows. Any ideas how to implement this? I'm hoping that it will be relative easy but have not sure where to start with this.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451287/how-do-you-show-the-windows-explorer-context-menu-from-a-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 0):

Some clue...

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding <the property with which column is bound to>}" Height="30" Width="40" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ContextMenu.Template>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```