# windows explorer context menu strip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have a c# application winForm.
The form contain a tree view that show the file windows file system.
I want to add an option for right click on file that open a windows context menu strip.
There is a way to Integrate windows menu to my c# app?

Thank!

Comment: (moved from an answer now that I have rep to do so)
I would check out the accepted answer and most popular answer (by @Groky) in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451287/how-do-you-show-the-windows-explorer-context-menu-from-a-c-sharp-application

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible.

You first have to catch a right click on a node.

```
  private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e) 
  {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) 
    {
       treeView1.SelectedNode = e.Node;
       //Play with the context menu here.
    }
  }
```

On the part where you play with the context menu, you do what you want with it ( in this case make it appear at this location I guess..) You should read about the [ContextMenuStrip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) for more information.