# How can i access the Windows Explorer context menu from a C# application?

Tags: c#

I have an application listing in my application and I would like to allow people to right-click on an item and show the Windows Explorer context menu. 
I'm assuming I would need to use the IContextMenu interface, but I'm not really sure where to start.

Comment: thanks.im new in this site i will research before ask next time .

Comment: Google on: C# right-click submenu and you will get dozens of answers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451287/how-do-you-show-the-windows-explorer-context-menu-from-a-c-sharp-application)
hopefuly helps it.
There's a very good tutorial (albeit in C++) about hosting an IContextMenu on Raymond Chen's blog in 11 parts (in order):

1. [Initial foray](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/20/231739.aspx)
2. [Displaying the context menu](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/22/232836.aspx)
3. [Invocation location](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/23/233376.aspx)
4. [Key context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/24/234113.aspx)
5. [Handling menu messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/27/234739.aspx)
6. [Displaying menu help](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/28/235242.aspx)
7. [Invoking the default verb](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/09/30/236133.aspx)
8. [Optimizing for the default command](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/01/236627.aspx)
9. [Adding custom commands](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/04/237507.aspx)
10. [Composite extensions - groundwork](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/06/238630.aspx)
11. [Composite extensions - composition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/10/07/239197.aspx)

Comment: sorry im new in this site.thanks a lot.

Comment: nex time u have to search about you question before ask :)

Comment: is this possible with c#.actualy i never used c++ ..

Comment: i didnt use but you can find the library at: http://gong-shell.sourceforge.net/